# django orm join three tables

Tags: python, sql, django, join

I have three models (A, B, C) and I need to join them like so:

Model A fk1 to Model B pk1 and then Model B fk1 to Model C.

It is joining tables but not joining them correctly. I can join model a to b but it won't let me pull fields from the last table (c) after the first join.

Sample SQL that works:

```
select a.field1, a.field2, b.char1, b.char2, c.var1, c.var2
from TableA a
inner join TableB b
    on a.field1 = b.char1
left join TableC c
    on b.char2 = c.var1
where a.field2 = 'number'
```

Django code:

```
TableA.objects.select_related('field1').filter(field2=var).prefetch_related('char1').values('field1', 'field2', 'char1', 'char1__var1', 'char1__var2')
```

Django models.py:

```
class TableA(models.Model):
field2 = models.CharField(db_column='FIELD2', max_length=8, primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
field1 = models.ForeignKey('TableB', db_column='FIELD1', max_length=6) # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'TableA'

class TableB(models.Model):

char1 = models.CharField(db_column='CHAR1', max_length=6) # Field name made lowercase.
char2 = models.ForeignKey('TableC', db_column='CHAR2', max_length=6, primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'TableB' 

class TableC(models.Model):

var1 = models.CharField(db_column='VAR1', max_length=6, primary_key=True) # Field name made lowercase.
var2 = models.CharField(db_column='VAR2', max_length=50) # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'TableC'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Question was edited, so this answer is not relevant anymore.

```
TableA.objects.filter(field2=var, b__isnull=False, b__c__isnull=True).values(
    'field1', 'field2', 'b__char1', 'b__c__var1', 'b__c__var2',
)
```

1. `b__isnull=False` is for `INNER JOIN tableb` and `b__c__isnull=True` is for `LEFT JOIN tablec`.
2. You can refer to fields on related models in `values()`.

Comment: It says "cannot resolve keyword 'table' into field" (specifically TableB)

Comment: I updated original question with models and revised the sql I am trying to do. First table has a fk to a pk in Table B then a different field in Table B has a fk to a field in Table C.